# select all div by class name inside of the div

Tags: javascript

how to select div `p` and `p2` inside of `r` only through query selector , i dont want to select div `p` and `p2`if its not inside of class`r`

```
<div>
<div class="r"><div class="p"></div><div class="p2"></div></div> //want to select this , i know it can accessed with tad name div
</div>

<div class="r"><div class="p"></div><div class="p2"></div></div> // I dont want to select this if the parent div is body
```

**CSS**

```
.p,.p2{
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:orange
}
```

the javascript which ive tried is , is this correct how to achieve

```
c = document.querySelectorAll( ' x >.r' ) // where x is the parent tag tagName of r
```

Comment: Found a typo in your css. `width5` must be `width`.

Comment: Why not post it as a runable snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So based on your requirement, you want to just select the first child's descendants,

Then just use `:first-child` selector.

```
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r:first-child");
var descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2");

Array.from(descendant).forEach(function(itm){
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/104sn7mu/4/)

Comment: @Anjali Glad to help! :)

Comment: You can post runable snippets here, links rot.

Comment: Sure @RobG. For the next time.

Comment: but array.from is new isnt there a different , i dont want to use

Comment: @Anjali You can then just use, `[].forEach.call(descendant, function(itm){ })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131427/discussion-between-anjali-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
c = document.querySelectorAll(".r .p, .r .p2");
```

The comma separates selectors, just like in CSS, and `a b` means "b inside a".

Comment: didnt work http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB2X0WYWEUMR

Comment: @Anjali Here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/104sn7mu/ The answer's suggestion was correct. You can't directly access the style property over a `nodelist`, you have to iterate it properly and apply whatever styles you want.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it selects all i want to select only the first

Comment: @Anjali—you can post code here as a runable snippet. Please don't reference w3schools, W3C and MDN are much better references.

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select by class, then you can do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div div.r .p, div div.r .p2');
```

Note that these selectors work anywhere (e.g. as a style rule), there is no need for additional scripting.

e.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('div div.r .p, div div.r .p2');
  console.log('Found: ' + x.length);
};
```

```html
<!-- Descendants of a div -->
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">p below div and div.r</div>
    <div class="p2">p2 below div and div.r</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Descendants of body -->
<div class="r">
  <div class="p">p below body and div.r</div>
  <div class="p2">p2 below body and div.r</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @RobG  `c = document.querySelectorAll( ' x >.r' )` but if the answer would in this way , may be more i thankful